# How to make webpack source map idempotent

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

```
{"version":3,"sources":["webpack:///webpack/bootstrap c12c82c8d8662b069e00", ... }
```

The hash at the end of webpack:///webpack/bootstrap changes with every build. Therefore when ci runs our npm build command to see if files change it fails.